# Preventing users from changing background

Tags: windows-7, windows

I work for a small business and we want our logo to be our desktop background. So I set my activedesktop like this in a reg file,

```
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop]
"NoChangingWallPaper"=dword:00000001
```

And that prevents a user from right clicking on a picture in explorer and clicking set as desktop background. They also cannot go to the control panel and do it that away.

However, if they go in IE9 they are able to right click on a picture and click "Set as background" and it works. Note, the user does not have admin rights. What's even stranger is, if I log in to the local admin account on the computer, they cannot use IE to change backgrounds.

Why does a user have rights for that when an admin account doesn't? How can I prevent them from changing the desktop with IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/62048-desktop-background-specify-prevent-change.html). It's quite lengthy so I won't quote the whole thing.

There are two options: using Group Policy or in Registry Editor. The registry option is different from what you are currently doing and is probably what you are looking for.

> 1. Open **regedit** and go to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**.
> 2. Right click in the empty space and select **New**, then **String Value**.
> 3. The **Name** should be **Wallpaper** and the **Value** should be the **path of the image**, no quotes.
> 4. Repeat step 2 and this time name it **WallpaperStyle**. The value should be a number:
>
>    - 0 to **Center**
>    - 1 to **Tile**
>    - 2 to **Stretch**
>    - 3 to **Fit**
>    - 4 to **Fill**
> 5. Close **regedit** and restart.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I did and it still did not block people from using IE to change desktop background. I had to add a blank image with the name of Internet Explorer Wallpaper.bmp in the Internet Explorer folder in roaming and set to read only, so that way when IE tries to create the file to set as background it doesn't have access to it. The strange thing about it is I couldn't use IE to change my background with an admin account but I could on local user. Weird.

Comment: That's weird. Did you restart the computer? It also says "When you specify a desktop background, it will disable the Set as desktop background (image on PC) and Set as Background (image in web browser) context menu items. They will still be there and not grayed out, but they will not work."

Comment: Yep, I did restart. Didn't really make sense to me that I couldn't do it on an admin account but I could on a user.